# export double value with comma

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

i need to generate excel that display double values with a comma as grouping symbol.
example :100000000.00 ------> 100,000,000.00

the comma symbol for group and the Dot symbol for decimal separator 
thanks,

Comment: And hint: what did you try so far, besides posting your requirements here? You know, this is not you-order-we-code.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look to DecimalFormat

```
String number = "100000000.00";
double nb = Double.parseDouble(number);
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");

System.out.println(formatter.format(nb));
```